# 【NoSuchMethodError】audio_service does not start in initState

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the [audio_service package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) to allow background controls for my iOS app.
When I call `AudioService.start()`, `NoSuchMethodError` is raised **SOMETIMES**.

```
class _AudioServiceScreenState extends State<AudioServiceScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future(() async {
      await AudioService.connect();
      await start();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Future(() async {
      await AudioService.disconnect();
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///
  }

  Future<void> start() async {
    print('start');
    final success = await AudioService.start(
        backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _backgroundTaskEntrypoint);
    if (success) {
      await updateQueue();
    }
  }
}

void _backgroundTaskEntrypoint() {
  print('_backgroundTaskEntrypoint');
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic>? params) async {
    print('onStart');

    ///
  }
}
```

Since `print()` is used, `start` will be displayed in the Debug Console.
However `_backgroundTaskEntrypoint` does not display and `NoSuchMethodError` is raised.

[output screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXtqh.png)

Checking the implementation of `start()` in Audio_service, I expect that the error is occurring in `FlutterIsolate.spawn()`.

Is there a way to prevent the error from occurring?
Why does this sometimes happen?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an output, I can only guess that it might be because of calling `AudioService.start()` twice, when it is already running.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot in the post. Errore_patch.dart is highlighted. 
Where is`AudioService.start()` called twice?